# Why am I getting a value error in excel while using the ifs function?

Tags: excel, if-statement

```
=IFS(SEARCH("C*",A9),"Cake",SEARCH("K*",A9),"Cookies",SEARCH("B*",A9),"Bread & Bun",SEARCH("Y*",A9),"Pastry")
```

It works for the first criteria and returns "cake" but won't work for the others. I keep getting a #VALUE error.
Can help please??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SEARCH` isn't a Boolean-valued function. It doesn't return `FALSE` if the string isn't found -- it returns a `#VALUE!` error which isn't coerced to `FALSE`.

What you could do is wrap everything like `SEARCH("C*",A9)` with `ISNUMBER()`: `ISNUMBER(SEARCH("C*",A9))` since Excel can tell that `#VALUE!` isn't a number.